# where can I have the specific OBD DTC fault code description e.g P1xxx means XXXXXX

Tags: obd-ii

I am working on OBD project now, I wanna have list of data for DTC fault code. we can easily find the general fault code info e.g P0xxx and P2XXX. We can pay for the license. anyone know where I can buy the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good list of them here: https://www.outilsobdfacile.com/data-trouble-code-obd2.php

If you are working on a specific car manufacturer you can usually find all the manufacturer level error messages hidden somewhere in a file of their diagnostic software.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't expect to find definitions for vendor-specific fault codes (which only the respective vendors own), the first place should be the SAE International, which is the actual organization committee that has defined those codes.

E.g., you might want to buy [SAE J2012](https://www.sae.org/standards/content/j2012_201612/) or J2012DA, respectively.